# Problem in authentification using sockets C in linux

Tags: c, linux, centos

Could someone help me to solve the problem of authentification of a mini-chat using Linux with C langage (sockets) ?

When I chose number `1` it doesn't give anything ! Everything is logic in my mind but who knows ! For the  Ip adress loopback `127.0.0.1` and port `5000`,  here is the code :

./server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <ctype.h>


void error(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno;
     socklen_t clilen;
     char buffer[255];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
    printf("Waiting on connections...."); 
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, 
                 (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, 
                 &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");


     int choice;
    const char logins[2][10] = {"hafsa","kaoutar"};
    const char pass[2][10] = {"hafsa","kaoutar"};     

   S:  n = write(newsockfd,"Enter your choice : \n1.Chat\n2.Send file\n3.Receive file\n4.Exit\n",strlen("Enter your choice : \n1.Chat\n2.Send file\n3.Receive file\n4.Exit\n"));         //Ask for choice    
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     read(newsockfd, &choice, sizeof(int));                 //Read choice
     printf("Client - Choice is : %d\n" , choice);  


      switch(choice){
        case 1:
        printf("Connexion\n");
        printf("Entrez le login :\n");
            bzero(buffer,256);
            n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
            if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

        if(strncmp(*logins+0, buffer, 10) == 0){
            printf("Entrez le mot de passe :\n");
            bzero(buffer,256);
                n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
                if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
            if(strncmp(*pass+0, buffer, 10) == 0){
                printf("Connexion avec succes !\n");
                while(1){
                    bzero(buffer,256);
                    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
                    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
                    printf("%s: %s\n",logins[0],buffer);
                    bzero(buffer,256);
                    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
                    n = write(newsockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
                    int i=strncmp("Bye" , buffer, 3);
                    if(i == 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        else if(strncmp(*logins+1, buffer, 10) == 0){
            printf("Entrez le mot de passe :\n");
            bzero(buffer,256);
                n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
                if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");

            if(strncmp(*pass+1, buffer, 10) == 0){
                printf("Connexion avec succes !\n");
                while(1){
                    bzero(buffer,256);
                    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
                    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
                    printf("%s: %s\n",logins[1],buffer);
                    bzero(buffer,256);
                    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
                    n = write(newsockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
                    int i=strncmp("Bye" , buffer, 3);
                    if(i == 0)
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        else    error("Utilisateur inconnu !");

            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Mazal mazal mafqedt l2amaaal\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Mazal mazal mafqedt l2amaaal\n");
            break;
        case 4 :
        goto Q;
            break;
     }

     if(choice != 4)
        goto S;

   Q:  close(newsockfd);
     close(sockfd);
     return 0; 
}
```

./client

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include<ctype.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[255];
    if (argc < 3)
    {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");


    int choice;
    const char logins[2][10] = {"hafsa","kaoutar"};
    const char pass[2][10] = {"hafsa","kaoutar"}; 

S:  bzero(buffer,256);                      
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);                //Read Server String Asking For The Choice
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Server - %s\n",buffer);
    scanf("%d" , &choice);                      //Enter choice
    write(sockfd, &choice, sizeof(int));                //Send choice to Server

    if (choice == 4)
    goto Q;

    switch(choice){
        case 1 :
            printf("Connexion\n");
            printf("Entrez le login :\n");
            bzero(buffer,256);
            fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
            n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
            if (n < 0) 
                 error("ERROR writing to socket");

            if(strncmp(*logins+0, buffer, 10) == 0){
                printf("Entrez le mot de passe :\n");
                bzero(buffer,256);
                    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
                n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

                if(strncmp(*pass+0, buffer, 10) == 0){
                    printf("Connexion avec succes !\n");
                    while(1){
                        bzero(buffer,256);
                        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
                        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
                            printf("%s: %s\n",*logins+0,buffer);
                            bzero(buffer,256);
                        n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
                            if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
                        int i=strncmp("Bye" , buffer, 3);
                        if(i == 0)
                            break;
                    }       
                }
            }

            if(strncmp(*logins+1, buffer, 10) == 0){
                printf("Entrez le mot de passe :\n");
                bzero(buffer,256);
                    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
                n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                    if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");

                if(strncmp(*pass+1, buffer, 10) == 0){
                    printf("Connexion avec succes !\n");
                    while(1){
                        bzero(buffer,256);
                        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
                        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
                        if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
                        printf("%s: %s\n",*logins+1,buffer);
                            bzero(buffer,256);
                        n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
                            if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
                            int i=strncmp("Bye" , buffer, 3);
                            if(i == 0)
                                break;
                        }
                }
            }

            else    error("Utilisateur inconnu !");

            break;
        case 2:
            printf("Mazal mazal mafqedt l2amaaal\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("Mazal mazal mafqedt l2amaaal\n");
            break;
        case 4 :
        goto Q;
            break;

    }

    if(choice != 4)
        goto S;

Q:  printf("You chose to exit. See you later !.");



    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question unfortunately asks a lot of your readers. Why don't you excerpt a few lines of code into a minimal compilable example, focus your question tighter, and try again? You might get a better answer that way.

Answer (score 1):

A problem is this code in your client:

```
scanf("%d" , &choice);
```

It is where you enter your "choice"... however, unfortunately you have entered BOTH your choice of "1", followed by a newline... but scanf() has only removed from stdin the "1".  the newline is still present.  So, when the client later performs an fgets() to obtain login information, the only thing it gets is the newline.

I suggest you replace the scanf() with a fgets() and an sscanf().
That way the fgets will extract all user input up to and including the newline, 
and the sscanf() can process the buffer that fgets() read.
For example:

```
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d" , &choice);
```

Comment: One more tip... when handling "choice" #1 in client, you perform an fgets() to obtain the login name... the fgets() reads and transfers the entered login name AS WELL AS a Newline... which makes the comparison with your internal table of logins fail.  Therefore, you must remove the newline from buffer before sending it to the server.  That said, I'm not saying that is the only error left... far from it.